# How to delete the last element from array with pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I try to build a function which deletes the last element of an array. So I need an input array and its dimension, then delete the last term and obtain a new output array. I don't want that. My goal is to somehow make the output array the new input array. In other words, I want to overwrite the input array with the output array.

So if dimension is 4, I don't want to have a 4-dim array in the memory but only 3-dim table after the deletion.

```
void del (int* ptr_array, int dim) {
 int* temp = ptr_array; //Hold the very first address of the input array.
 ptr_array = new int[dim - 1]; // Let the address of the input array be 
                               // the address of new output array. Overwritting.

 for (int i = 0; i < dim - 1; i++) {
     ptr_array = (temp+i); // Will it remember what is temp+1 if I have 
                           // already overwritten the arrays?
     ptr_array++;
 }
 //delete[] ptr_array; - this one is out of the questions - deletes now the input table.
}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with this code? - in fact it doesn't change anything

Comment: Don't forget that arguments to functions by default are passed *by value*. In other words, their values are *copied*, and modifying (i.e. assigning to) a local copy will not modify the original.

Comment: `void del (int*& ptr_array, int dim)` seems more appropiate if you want to change the pointer, but prefer to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Besides that problem, I assume this is a school assignment or exercise (or similar)? Otherwise you should start using `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I'm just learning C++ for a few days on my own, so it's my own task

Comment: As these arguments are passed value so you will not get changed result. Therefore you can try passed by reference. But it is good practice to pass std::vector as argument and return vector from function.

Comment: important part of learning is using the right tool, which would be `std::vector` and maybe smart pointers in this case. Some consider doing it the hard way as integral part of learning too, so keep in mind that what you are doing is fine as exercise but by no means it is the way one should write c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in you function

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dim - 1; i++) {
     ptr_array = (temp+i); // Will it remember what is temp+1 if I have 
                           // already overwritten the arrays?
     ptr_array++;
 }
```

does nothing, you wanted

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dim - 1; i++) {
   ptr_array[i] = temp[i];
 }
```

Note the *delete* in your comment is invalid because you do not delete the result of a new[] but a pointer inside the allocated array

If the call is like

```
int * v = ...;

del(v);

// here v is unchanged
```

probably you wanted to modify *v*, in that case you can return the new array or to use an input-output variable using a reference

First possibility :

```
int* del (int* ptr_array, int dim) {
  int* new_array = new int[dim - 1]; 

  for (int i = 0; i < dim - 1; i++) {
     new_array[i] = ptr_array[i];
  }
  delete[] ptr_array;
  return new_array;
}
```

with

```
int * v = ...;

v = del(v);
```

Second possibility

```
void del (int*& ptr_array, int dim) {
  int* new_array = new int[dim - 1]; 

  for (int i = 0; i < dim - 1; i++) {
     new_array[i] = ptr_array[i];
  }
  delete[] ptr_array;
  ptr_array = new_array;
}
```

with

```
int * v = ...;

del(v);
// here v is the new array
```

Warning these codes suppose the input array has at least one element

---

However the use of an `std::vector<int>` does all of that for you and is more practical to use

```
std::vector<int> v;
...
v.resize(v.size() - 1);
```

or

```
std::vector<int> v;
...
v.pop_back();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I did not realize that I could detete the input as you just did. Thank you!

Comment: @zorro47 ok, perfect, I added the second solution using a reference in case

Comment: the part about `vector` should probably be on top, since it's the important part

Comment: @sp2danny the title of the question and its body are about _array_, so to speak about the use of a _std::vector_ can only be a complement ;-)